# Compiling QWT 6.1.1 Designer plugin for integration in QT Creator/Designer (based on Qt 5.2.1) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, plugins, designer, qwt

I installed QT Creator/Designer 3.0.1 (based on Qt5.2.1) from Ubuntu 14.04 Software Center.
I want to be able to use qwt_plot from QWT library in Qt Designer.
I followed [Qwt's installation guide](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html) and was able to compile the library.

However, I didn't succeed to compile the Designer plugin part of it.

Following http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7597/ I did my best to set the correct include / lib paths for qmake in the designer.pro file, and all libs seem to be found, but I get the following error from make:

g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o designer qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.o qwt_designer_plotdialog.o qwt_designer_plugin.o qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.o moc_qwt_designer_plotdialog.o moc_qwt_designer_plugin.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Designer -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Xml -L/usr/local/qwt-6.1.1/lib -lqwt -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.o: In function `qInitResources_qwt_designer_plugin()':
qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.cpp:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of`qInitResources_qwt_designer_plugin()'
qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.o:qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.cpp:(.text+0x20): first defined here
qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.o: In function `qCleanupResources_qwt_designer_plugin()':
qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.cpp:(.text+0x50): multiple definition of`qCleanupResources_qwt_designer_plugin()'
qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.o:qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.cpp:(.text+0x50): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [designer] Error 1

This seems to be a typical error with gcc when some config instructions are still missing, but which ones (sorry, newbie)?
Help welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The compilation has to be done with the version of Qt used to generate QCreator.
I uninstalled QCreator from Ubuntu Software Center (Qt 5.2.1), and directly installed the latest full Qt version (5.3.2) from : http://qt-project.org/downloads .
This installation includes QtCreator (v3.2.1).
With this, [QWT installation guide](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html) worked perfectly.
I hope this can help!